# Debug C# Azure Functions that's part of a dotnet solution in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, azure-function-app

I have a dotnet core 2.2 solution with multiple projects. One of the projects is a C# Azure Function app. I have setup VS Code to run/debug one or multiple projects (Web APIs, consoles, web jobs) , but I am not able to find a way to run/debug the function project while the solution is open. But if I open the function project directly in VS Code (not as part of solution), I can run and debug it. How can I setup VS Code launch.json and tasks.json to be able to run a function as part of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, there is nothing to do with the solution and other projects. In VS code, you just need to click "Terminal" --> "New Terminal" and then navigate to the directory of your function project.

For example, my function is under the directory as below:
[image]

So we just need to navigate to this directory by the command:

```
cd /vs2019source/FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1
```

And then run the command below to run your function.(even though you open your function in solution with several projects in it)

```
func host start
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that method but there still remains the issue of debugging. My goal is to debug a code that resides in a project referenced by the function.